# Line integral of a conservative field, when you know its potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question. I am quite comfortable with line integrals, to some extend. 
My textbook mentions it should be easy to evaluate the line integral of the tangential component of a vector along a curve when you know its potential.

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to do this?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate a line integral, ultimately what you are doing is pulling back the function to the ordinary real line, rather than thinking about a curve in space. You think of the path as parameterized by an ordinary interval on the line. When you go to evaluate the integral though, you forget everything about that, and are left with just an ordinary integral over an interval on the line. As such, what you want to do is really just use the fundamental theorem of calculus. We have a special name for the situation you're describing, called the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals.

The formula you seek is $$\int_C \nabla f \cdot dr = f(r(b)) - f(r(a))$$

where $r$ is the path, $a,b$ are its endpoints, and $f$ is the potential function.

Many examples and explanations can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/FundThmLineIntegrals.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, is this what we call the Fundamental theorem of line integrals?

Comment: Yes it is. Happy to help.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?. Let's say I have found the potential, but I don't have the line segments, only the parametric curve r(t). Is it possible to turn my parametric curve into line segments? So that I can apply the theorem

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Given the curve, you want to find the endpoints? @Djhoe

Comment: i) I was given a vector field. ii) Then I can see it is conservative and then I found its potential. After that the question is compute the (messy) line integral along the parametric curve r(t), with 0 \leq t \leq 1

Comment: So I was not given the path, I just know the vector field is conservative and I know its potential.

Comment: @Djhoe If you know it's conservative, you don't need to know the path. The fundamental theorem asserts you *only* need the endpoints if you're integrating a gradient, and you know the potential.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C$ is a curve $r(t)$, $a \leq t \leq b$ and suppose $\vec F=\nabla f$, then

$$\int_{C}\vec F\cdot d\vec r =\int_{C}\nabla f\cdot d \vec r = f(r(b)) - f(r(a))$$